# why enableHermes: false but global.HermesInternal = {}?

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

in android\app\build.gradle:

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: false,
]
```

in index.js

```
console.log('hermes -> ishermes', global.HermesInternal !== null);
```

```
npm run android
```

in log:

```
    Time    Tag Message
    18:28:15.576    ReactNativeJS   'hermes -> ishermes', true
```

why enableHermes: false  but global.HermesInternal = {} ??

react-native: 0.61.5

Emulator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript differentiates between `null` and `undefined`.

If Hermes is disabled, then `HermesInternal` will be `undefined`. It will not be `null`.

To check if Hermes is enabled, you can use:

```
if (typeof(HermesInternal) === "undefined") {
  console.log("Hermes is not enabled");
} else {
  console.log("Hermes is enabled");
}
```

Comment: Is the official website wrong? `https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes` ： `const isHermes = () => global.HermesInternal !== null;
`

Comment: Yes. The [docs were corrected](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/commit/5d4e7a596e4b5bb06c377f197efae6b1a79738e5) three weeks ago, but the website apparently hasn't been published